# Can I use a 3rd party HTTP library to make an outbound request?

Tags: google-app-engine, httprequest, task-queue, urlfetch

Seeing that there are many restrictions in Google App Engine standard, I am compelled to ask this seemingly silly question.

I tried **TaskQueues** to make an outbound request and turns out they don't do that.

The [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/issue-requests) and samples demonstrate the use of **URL Fetch** service to issue outbound HTTP requests using the standard `java.net` APIs. I want to make outbound requests using a 3rd party HTTP client library like **[Google HTTP client library](https://github.com/google/google-http-java-client)**.

Has anyone tried or knows anything like/about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if the Http library has a pluggable transport layer and plugin that can call the Urlfetch API such as the [Google Http Client](https://github.com/google/google-http-java-client) you link to:

> Pluggable HTTP transport abstraction that allows you to use any low-level library such as java.net.HttpURLConnection, Apache HTTP Client, or URL Fetch on Google App Engine.

If you are writing code specifically for AppEngine you might as well call URLFetch directly, however urlfetch transport layer plugins for various http client libraries allow third party code to be usable on App Engine without being tied to it.